# How can I bulk load XML data

Tags: xml, db2, etl, varchar

I have 265,000 files to load in a database table. Each file has an XML like structure and represents one record. I need to load all the files today into a table that does not use any XML datatypes: all `varchar(265)`. I am using an ETL tool to load the files but it's taken 2 days to load 50,000 files

How can I do that with it taking weeks to complete? I am DB2 LUW v9.7.

Comment: You could spend a day attempting to write your own ETL tool?  How big are the files, that does sound rather slow for something that should be 'small'.  And all fields in a files as `VARCHAR(265)` (256?) sounds suspicious... You _may_ get better performance if you didn't have to open so many files, or are able to run the process on multiple threads/machines

Comment: Agreed to everything you say. I made some progress though: `db2 "create table tmp_xml (filecontents xml)"
db2 "import from test.del of del xml from xmltest/ insert into tmp_xml"` allows me to bulk load my data. I need to figure out to use `xmltable` and I will be all set.